# Back Command´s modification in LWUIT

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-command

This is my first question. I will try to be clear.

I need to make a back command in LWUIT that allows me to go back to a previous form and pass some parameters for some modifications of the form.

I can not use the `Form.getBackCommand()` because it returns the default back command and with that command i can not pass the parameters as i want to do.

How can i do that?

:)

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Using the StateMachine.back() inside of my button´s method

Comment: Can you explain how to call the StateMachine ? Do I need other libraries to include in my project in order to use StateMachine ?

Comment: Make a question and I will answer, not here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First add the command to the form:
   `Form.addCommand(new Command("Back"));`
2. Add `CommandListener`:
   `Form.addCommandListener(new ActionListsner());`
3. In the `ActionListener` show the previous form
   `previousForm.showBack();`